# "npm update" is installing a beta version of the module over the stable version that installed after "npm install"

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm, versioning, dependency-management

Currently the npm package [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose) is on version 3.8.12. Running `npm install mongoose --save` correctly installs version 3.8.12 and saves the dependency to package.json as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mongoose": "^3.8.12"
}
```

If you look in `node_modules/mongoose/package.json` you can see that the installed version is indeed 3.8.12. However, if I now run `npm update` then npm will go ahead and install an unstable version of mongoose (3.9.0). I assume this is because of the caret in the dependency entry which tells npm to go ahead and upgrade minor versions (i.e. 3.8 to 3.9). That's fine, except I don't want any prerelease versions. If I modify the dependency and remove the caret then `npm update` works as expected, except of course that I now have to manually upgrade the dependency version even for minor and patch updates.

You can see from running `npm info mongoose` that they have a "latest" tag and an "unstable" tag.

[image]

So clearly `npm install` uses latest unless otherwise specified, while `npm update` is ignoring the tag altogether and grabbing the latest minor version it's aware of.

Is there a way to modify the dependency so `npm update` will pull in the latest minor version but ignore any prerelease versions?

### UPDATE

Same issue occurs if I try to use `3.x.x` as the dependency. I was hoping that would still allow me to upgrade through minor versions without prerelease versions but that's not the case :/

Tilde (`~3.8.12`) technically works but it's a bandaid. The only reason it "works" is because the breaking changes being introduced are in `3.9.0-unstable` and tilde doesn't allow npm to upgrade across minor versions. If these "unstable" changes were introduced in `3.8.13-unstable` then this same issue would occur even when using the tilde.

### UPDATE 2

I also tried manually specifying the "latest" tag: `^3.8.12-latest`. That didn't change anything; `npm update` ignores the tag entirely, even if it's explicitly in the dependency listing itself :/

Comment: Could be related to a recent bug. Try `npm -g install npm` and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*semver* does not specify a way to tell apart stable and unstable versions.

As you said the caret would allow for *npm update* to install any *3.x.x* version, while the tilde would allow any *3.8.x* version even if the next version is called *3.8.13-broken*.

Sadly, the same happens with any *semver* operator, so there's no escape.

As you see, you are better off using the specific version *3.8.12*.

Comment: Check the [*semver* documentation](http://npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html) for further details.

Comment: I've looked over that quite a bit but it's a bit cryptic. Thanks for confirming my suspicion that this is just an oversight on npm's part :)

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought the simplest approach here would be to use the tilde `~`

```
"dependencies": {
  "mongoose": "~3.8.12"
}
```

The difference from the "caret" `^` being that the "tilde" will match on `3.8.x` where the "caret" matches anything equal or above the specified version.

Comment: Caret is any minor version above the specified version. Tilde is the same thing but for patch versions. I can definitely use tilde and that "solves" the issue, but only because the breaking changes are being introduced in version 3.9.0-unstable rather than 3.8.13-unstable. If the latter were the case then even tilde wouldn't help :(. If I could make `npm update` just ignore any tags other than "latest" that would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update for anyone who stumbled across this like I did, I did a minor semver bump and published it tagged as beta, but in the 10-15 minutes after publishing, npm installs defaulted to this beta as latest, despite it being clearly tagged.

I think there's some lag time on updating the semver table, if you give it 10-15, your future `npm install <packagename>` attempts should give you the correct version.